# Angular component, different content depending on Element

Tags: angular, components, angular5

I have a list

```
*ngFor="let h of list"
```

Depending on the type of the item "h.type" I want to use a different component to display details. How do I load the component?

Comment: You could do it with an NgIF or NgSwitch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you could do it with an [`NgSwitch`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitch):

```
<div *ngFor="let h of list" [ngSwitch]="h.type">
  <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'x'">
    <component-x>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'y'">
    <component-y>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

You might be able to skip the `ng-container` but I haven't tested that:

```
<div *ngFor="let h of list" [ngSwitch]="h.type">
    <component-x  *ngSwitchCase="'x'">
    <component-y  *ngSwitchCase="'y'">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-template for that. E.g.

```
<div *ngFor="let h of list">
  <ng-container *ngIf="h.type === 'FIRST'">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="firstTemplate"></ng-container>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container *ngIf="h.type === 'SECOND'">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="secondTemplate"></ng-container>
  </ng-container>
</div>

<!-- now define the two templates -->
<ng-template #firstTemplate>
  <my-first-component/>
</ng-template>
<ng-template #secondTemplate>
  <my-second-component/>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Umm, what benefit do you get with switching the template? Why not ngIf on the components directly?

Comment: No idea, honestly. I've written this 3 years ago so I was proably heavily drilling into ng-template stuff. One thing I think it may be applicable is if you _don't_ want to create a new component for that. But that doesn't make sense, when you look at the question. No idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by using *ngIf
And load components with their selectors directly in html.

```
<component1 *ngIf="h.type == ‘car’"></component1>
<component2 *ngIf="h.type == ‘truck’"></component2>
```

Component 1 is going to be displayed when h.type is car and component 2 is going to be displayed when h.type is truck.